# Inject other yaml files inside the applcation.yml?

Tags: spring-boot

Is it possible in Spring Boot to inject other yaml files inside the application.yml?

For example...

```
receipes:
  -
    simple-cake:
      - egg:
      - flour:
      - sugar:
  -
    complex-cake:
      < complex-cake-ingredients.yml #Loads in eggs, flour, sugar, chocoloate etc etc
```

Comment: there is i lot of ways you can configure properties using spring boot, replacing entire files is not possible, but overriding parameters in yamls, etc etc. you can read all about it here
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible !!

Eg: Create `application-dev-db.yml` and to inject in `application.yml`, just add the below lines

```
spring:
  profiles:
    include: dev-db
```